# Rails Server, new files not live

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image]

I'm going through a Ruby on Rails tutorial and right now it's generating controllers. (I believe I'm on the local server.. started by doing:

```
$rails s
```

When I look in TextMate, all the new files have a "no entry" sign on them, which I assume to be not live. They also don't work when I try to pull up the address.
How do I make them live?

(Edit: Picture added, also.. When I try to go to the page it says:
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "address"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Comment: Can you add more informations about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Rails should not be *generating controllers*.

My advise is to start all over

```
rails new myApp

cd myApp

rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text

rake db:migrate 

rails s
```

At point your browser to `http://localhost:3000`

Then you'll see the rails welcome page

If you point the browser to `http://localhost:3000/posts` you'll get to the post index page

And read this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

**update**

Are you running rails generations from another user? It looks like you don't have read and write rights to the files from textmate.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but that's a lesson gone by already. The objective of this lesson is to get away from scaffolding

Comment: Ok so what happens when you do `$ rails generate controller page index`

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing lesson. The server was attached to a different directory. And apparently the symbol isn't read/write.. Not sure what it is though